# Write a function in Rust that takes closure/function `T` and returns `T::Output`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function, that takes a closure and returns back whatever the closures return type is. I don't want hard-coded return types, like in `fn(action: &dyn Fn()) -> i32`. I tried to solve it as you can see below:

```rust
pub fn execute_code<T>(actions: T) -> T::Output
    where
        T: Fn(),
{
    println!("before:");
    let res = actions();
    println!("after:");
    res
}

fn main() {
    let i32_res: i32 = execute_code(&|| 5 + 5);
    let str_res: &str = execute_code(&|| "a string");
    println!("i32_res: {}, string_res: {}", i32_res, str_res);
}
```

But the compiler (1.53 stable) complains about:

```
pub fn execute_code<T>(actions: T) -> T::Output
   |        ------------ required by a bound in this
2  |     where
3  |         T: Fn(),
   |            ---- required by this bound in `execute_code`
...
12 |     let i32_res: i32 = execute_code(&|| 5 + 5);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found integer
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to parametrize the output as another type:

```rust
pub fn execute_code<T, R>(actions: T) -> R
    where
        T: Fn() -> R,
{
    println!("before:");
    let res = actions();
    println!("after:");
    res
}

fn main() {
    let i32_res: i32 = execute_code(&|| 5 + 5);
    let str_res: &str = execute_code(&|| "a string");
    println!("i32_res: {}, string_res: {}", i32_res, str_res);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=051fc68189c643393a0437d779e2c17d)

Comment: Also, the return type of `execute_code()` can be specified as `T::Output` (which is `R` by definition), as the OP wanted.